# React Native setState not working (functional component) at all, not even just out of sync

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-functional-component, react-state-management

I appreciate anyone taking the time to go through my code and helping me with what's going wrong **(printLang() is always printing 'en' or 'es' depending on which value it took on when I refreshed the app)**! I'm using Material Dropdown for the first time and don't know if that's affecting my state management, so I'm going to just paste the whole code here!

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const LANGS = [
    {
        value: 'en',
    }, 
    {
        value: 'es',
    }
];

const INTRO_DATA = [
    {
        key: '1',
        title: 'Language Selection',
        description: 'Choose your preferred language',
    },
    {
        key: '2',
        title: 'Role Selection',
        description: 'Are you a worker or a organization / business owner?',
    }
];

const IntroScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [appLanguage, setAppLanguage] = useState("en");
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');
    const scrollX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    const printLang = () => {
        if (appLanguage == "en") {
            setAppLanguage("es");
        }
        else {
            setAppLanguage("en");
        }
        console.log(appLanguage);
    }

    const languageSelectionDropdown = (
        <View style={styles.test}>
            <Dropdown 
                width={150} 
                maxHeight={150} 
                label='Language' 
                data={LANGS}
                onChangeText={(value, index, data) => {
                    console.log(value);
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log(data);
                    () => {setAppLanguage(value)};
                }}
                baseColor={Colors.darkGray}
                textColor={Colors.darkGray}
                containerStyle={styles.dropDownStyle}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable} onPress={() => printLang()}>
                <Text>
                    Next
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );

    const testmodule = (
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
            <Text>Empty for now</Text>
        </View>
    );
    
    const renderItem = React.useCallback(
        ({ item, index }) => {
            const inputRange = [
                (index - 1) * width,
                index * width,
                (index + 1) * width,
            ];
            const descriptionTranslate = scrollX.interpolate({
                inputRange,
                outputRange: [width * 0.1, 0, -width * 0.1],
            });
            return (
                <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { width: width - 80 }]}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Animated.Text style={{ transform: [{ translateX: descriptionTranslate }] }}>
                        {item.description}
                    </Animated.Text>
                    <View>
                        {item.key == '1' ? languageSelectionDropdown : testmodule}
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        },
        [scrollX, width]
    );

    const keyExtractor = React.useCallback((item) => item.key, []);

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container]}>
          <FlatList
            data={INTRO_DATA}
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
              {
                useNativeDriver: false,
              }
            )}
            style={styles.flatList}
            pagingEnabled
            horizontal
            decelerationRate={'normal'}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            renderItem={renderItem}
          />
          <View style={styles.text}>
            <View style={styles.dotContainer}>
              <Text>Scaling Dot</Text>
              <ScalingDot
                data={INTRO_DATA}
                scrollX={scrollX}
                containerStyle={{
                  top: 30,
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );    
};
```

In any single run of the app, the button in `languageSelectionDropdown` calls `printLang()` and always prints the same value even if I switch between the languages using the dropdown. I've tried doing a console log in `onChangeText` itself and am sure that the value of the dropdown is indeed changing, so it's just the state management that is going awry.

Appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forget to add `languageSelectionDropdown` as a dependency to your `renderItem` function with `useCallback`. As you didn't add it so `renderItem` function never see the changes of the state and that's why always gives you the same value.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Yeah I realized that after reading your reply! For anyone wondering, I just changed `[scrollX, width]` to `[scrollX, width, appLanguage]`.

Answer (score 1):

The state gets updated asynchronously and so the `printLang()` function won't see the change until the component rerenders.

Because the setState function is async, you can use `useEffect` hook to achieve the functionality you are looking for.

```
useEffect(() => { 
 // call any function you want to
 // this will only execute after appLanguage is updated. 

},[appLanguage])
```